# Find a CFG for L = { a^nb^m : n != m }

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

This question is upcoming for my midterm and I can't figure it out. My professor broke it down in two statements (n>m) and(m>n) and left us at that.

Find a context free grammar for $L = \{ a^n b^m : n \neq m \}$

Comment: Hint: You can generate a word $a^nb^m$ with $n \geq m$ by $m$-times appending $a$ and the front and $b$ at the back, and then $n-m$ times appending $a$ at the front.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

- $\{a^nb^m \mid n < m\} = \{a^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \circ \{b^k \mid k \geq 1\}$
- $\{a^nb^m \mid n > m\} = \{a^k \mid k \geq 1\} \circ \{a^nb^n  \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
- Assuming that $X$ generates $\{a^nb^n\}$, start with $S \to XB \mid AX$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: That smily face is really something!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution:

(1) $S → AX \mid XB$

(2) $X → aXb \mid e$

(3) $A → aA \mid a$

(4) $B → bB \mid b$

(1) means the answer is in two states: number of $a$'s larger than number of $b$'s or number of $b$'s larger than number of $a$'s. So the problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

yes,the idea to form grammars for this falls in two divisions 1)nm
so lets define the grammar for each individually and combine.
S -> X |  Y
X  -> aXb  | Xb | b
Y  -> aYb  |  aY |a

Comment: Welcome to MSE Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

You have two cases like your professor stated: $n > m$ and $n < m$. Let $x \to c_1$ and $x \to c_2$ be two rules that initiate the two cases, i.e. $x$ is the start variable. Then for example, for $n > m$ this is handled by $c_1$ and the context free grammar rules to generate it are $c_1 \to a$, $c_1 \to a c_1 b$, and $c_1 \to a c_1$. Similarly for $c_2$ to handle the case $n < m$.

Answer (score 2):

In this problem, strings start with a number of a's followed by the number of b's. there may be two cases

1. number of a's are greater than the number of b's , so we can assume that
   i) number of a's are equal as number of b's and after that we have to generate at least one extra a in the string
   so productions are
   S--> aSb |  A
   A--> aA|a
2. number of b's are greater than the number of a's , so we can assume
   i) number of a's are equal as number of b's and after that we have to generate at least one extra b in the string
   so productions are
   S--> aSb |  B
   B-->bB|b
   Hence Grammar productions are
   S-->aSb|A|B
   A--> aA|a
   B-->bB|b

Answer (score 1):

As per the given problem we have two cases i.e.

1. either the number of a can be greater than b (when n > m)
2. or the number of b can be greater than a (when m > n).

The minimum string that need to be generated is either a or b.

Then this production rule must satisfy all the conditions:

```
S -> Sa | Sb | E | a | b
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).